# Collada file doesn't look right

Tags: collada, dae, blender

I am studying Collada format. The idea is to handcode a pyramid, rectangle at a base and four triangles as sides.

Here is my DAE:

```
<COLLADA xmlns="http://www.collada.org/2005/11/COLLADASchema" version="1.4.1">
    <asset>
        <created>2023-11-27T12:48:14</created>
        <modified>2023-11-27T12:48:14</modified>
        <unit meter="1.0" name="meter" />
        <up_axis>Y_UP</up_axis>
    </asset>

    <library_images>
        <image id="texture0" name="texture">
        <init_from>../maps/world_01.png</init_from>
        </image>
    </library_images>

    <library_effects>
        <effect id="effect0">
        <profile_COMMON>
            <newparam sid="surface0">
            <surface type="2D">
                <init_from>texture0</init_from>
            </surface>
            </newparam>
            <newparam sid="sampler0">
            <sampler2D>
                <source>surface0</source>
            </sampler2D>
            </newparam>
            <technique sid="common">
            <phong>
                <diffuse>
                <texture texture="sampler0" texcoord="UVSET0" />
                </diffuse>
            </phong>
            </technique>
        </profile_COMMON>
        </effect>
    </library_effects>

    <library_materials>
        <material id="material0">
        <instance_effect url="#effect0" />
        </material>
    </library_materials>

    <library_geometries>
        <geometry id="shape0">
        <mesh>
            <source id="positions">
            <float_array id="positions-array" count="15">
                0.0 0.0 0.0
                1.0 0.0 0.0
                0.0 1.0 0.0
                1.0 1.0 0.0
                0.5 0.5 1.0  <!-- Top vertex for the pyramid -->
            </float_array>
            <technique_common>
                <accessor count="5" source="#positions-array" stride="3">
                <param name="X" type="float" />
                <param name="Y" type="float" />
                <param name="Z" type="float" />
                </accessor>
            </technique_common>
            </source>

            <source id="normals">
            <float_array id="normals-array" count="15">
                0.0 0.0 -1.0
                0.0 0.0 -1.0
                0.0 0.0 -1.0
                0.0 0.0 -1.0
                0.0 0.0  1.0  <!-- Normals for the sides of the pyramid -->
            </float_array>
            <technique_common>
                <accessor count="5" source="#normals-array" stride="3">
                <param name="X" type="float" />
                <param name="Y" type="float" />
                <param name="Z" type="float" />
                </accessor>
            </technique_common>
            </source>

            <source id="uv-source">
                <float_array id="uv-float-array" count="10">
                    0.0 0.0
                    1.0 0.0
                    0.0 1.0
                    1.0 1.0
                    0.5 0.5
                </float_array>
                <technique_common>
                    <accessor source="#uv-float-array" count="5" stride="2">
                    <param name="S" type="float"/>
                    <param name="T" type="float"/>
                    </accessor>
                </technique_common>
            </source>

            <vertices id="verts-array-vertices">
                <input semantic="POSITION" source="#positions" />
                <input semantic="NORMAL" source="#normals" />
                <input semantic="TEXCOORD" source="#uv-source" />
            </vertices>

            <triangles count="6" material="material0">
                <input offset="0" semantic="VERTEX" source="#verts-array-vertices" />
                <p>
                    0 1 2 
                    2 3 0

                    0 1 4
                    1 2 4
                    2 3 4
                    3 4 0
                </p>
            </triangles>
        </mesh>
        </geometry>
    </library_geometries>

    <library_visual_scenes>
        <visual_scene id="scene0">
        <node name="node0">
            <instance_geometry url="#shape0">
            <bind_material>
                <technique_common>
                <instance_material symbol="material0" target="#material0">
                    <bind_vertex_input semantic="TEXCOORD" input_semantic="TEXCOORD" />
                </instance_material>
                </technique_common>
            </bind_material>
            </instance_geometry>
        </node>
        </visual_scene>
    </library_visual_scenes>

    <scene>
        <instance_visual_scene url="#scene0" />
    </scene>
</COLLADA>
```

And here is the result in Blender:

[image: first]

[image: second]

As I understand, it is mostly about "triangles" tag, but... I just can not figure it out.
Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out (I will publist complete explanation on [robotics.snowcron.com](https://robotics.snowcron.com) as soon as I figure out why  texture is still off):

2023-11-27T12:48:14
        2023-11-27T12:48:14
        
        Y_UP

```
<library_images>
    <image id="texture0" name="texture">
        <init_from>../maps/world_01.png</init_from>
    </image>
</library_images>

<library_effects>
    <effect id="effect0">
        <profile_COMMON>
            <newparam sid="surface0">
                <surface type="2D">
                    <init_from>texture0</init_from>
                </surface>
            </newparam>
            <newparam sid="sampler0">
                <sampler2D>
                    <source>surface0</source>
                </sampler2D>
            </newparam>
            <technique sid="common">
                <phong>
                    <diffuse>
                    <texture texture="sampler0" texcoord="UVSET0" />
                    </diffuse>
                </phong>
            </technique>
        </profile_COMMON>
    </effect>
</library_effects>

<library_materials>
    <material id="material0">
        <instance_effect url="#effect0" />
    </material>
</library_materials>

<library_geometries>
    <geometry id="shape0">
        <mesh>
            <source id="positions">
                <float_array id="positions-array" count="15">
                    0 1 0
                    0 0 0
                    1 0 0
                    1 1 0

                    0.5 0.5 1
                </float_array>
                <technique_common>
                    <accessor count="5" source="#positions-array" stride="3">
                    <param name="X" type="float" />
                    <param name="Y" type="float" />
                    <param name="Z" type="float" />
                    </accessor>
                </technique_common>
            </source>

            <source id="normals">
            <float_array id="normals-array" count="15">
                0.0 0.0 -1.0
                0.0 0.0 -1.0
                0.0 0.0 -1.0
                0.0 0.0 -1.0
                0.0 0.0  1.0  <!-- Normals for the sides of the pyramid -->
            </float_array>
            <technique_common>
                <accessor count="5" source="#normals-array" stride="3">
                <param name="X" type="float" />
                <param name="Y" type="float" />
                <param name="Z" type="float" />
                </accessor>
            </technique_common>
            </source>

            <source id="uv-source">
                <float_array id="uv-float-array" count="10">
                    0.0 0.0
                    1.0 0.0
                    0.0 1.0
                    1.0 1.0
                    0.5 0.5
                </float_array>
                <technique_common>
                    <accessor source="#uv-float-array" count="5" stride="2">
                    <param name="S" type="float"/>
                    <param name="T" type="float"/>
                    </accessor>
                </technique_common>
            </source>

            <vertices id="verts-array-vertices">
                <input semantic="POSITION" source="#positions" />
                <input semantic="NORMAL" source="#normals" />
                <input semantic="TEXCOORD" source="#uv-source" />
            </vertices>

            <triangles count="6" material="material0">
                <input offset="0" semantic="VERTEX" source="#verts-array-vertices" />
                <p>
                    0 1 2 
                    0 2 3

                    0 4 3
                    3 4 2
                    2 4 1
                    1 4 0
                </p>
            </triangles>
        </mesh>
    </geometry>
</library_geometries>

<library_visual_scenes>
    <visual_scene id="scene0">
    <node name="node0">
        <instance_geometry url="#shape0">
        <bind_material>
            <technique_common>
            <instance_material symbol="material0" target="#material0">
                <bind_vertex_input semantic="TEXCOORD" input_semantic="TEXCOORD" />
            </instance_material>
            </technique_common>
        </bind_material>
        </instance_geometry>
    </node>
    </visual_scene>
</library_visual_scenes>

<scene>
    <instance_visual_scene url="#scene0" />
</scene>
```